# Slow save in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, publishing

I'm using Eclipse 3.5, with Java 6u20, Tomcat 6.0.28, and I have a big problem:
Everything worked normal, and somehow (I don't know how) Eclipse started to be very slow.

When I edit some file, Eclipse freezes, and show me a info window, saying Saving.........

And that last for about a minute or two, and than tomcat start to publish files. Till recently this worked ok (everything was finished in 3 seconds).

I don't know what has been changed in project, and I have tried using different eclipse, tomcat, Java,....

When I turn on System processes it shows a system process:
System: Updating status for Tomcat....

What could be wrong? Any hint guys?

Comment: See [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

Comment: It worked ok until 'something' happened. I'l try to adjust eclipse.ini but I don't think it will solve the problem

Comment: Any message in **Error Log**?

Comment: It's getting worse. It somehow goes from one computer to another. Today my comp is working fine, but other computers, that worked fine these days is having much trouble. 
Saving file of 700k is taking about 2 minutes.

Comment: this looks like a virus, but nod32 is't showing anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To tell you what solved the problem: We installed Eclipse 3.6 and there we turned on system processed in Process View. Above process System: Updating status for Tomcat... stood process Calculating Decorations.

We turned off all decoration, except SVN decoration (Window-Preferences-Label decorations) and saving works fine now.

Apparently there is some limit in number of files of project above which Eclipse is behave strange?

Comment: How do you get to the process view? I don't see it in Window>Show View>Other

Answer (score 4):

My saves got slow after installing egit. I uninstalled this, and things are back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing slow saves of about 2 seconds on some Java projects in Eclipse. On other projects saves were performed instantly. Removing all breakpoints resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, during saving I could see the sonarlint processing was taking time so I right click on project properties, sonarlint -> uncheck Run SonarLint Automatically.

Basically you can see what's causing the slowness in progress view of eclipse and try to disable that.